# Mapping language code to an entry in Django LANGUAGES

Tags: django, localization, translation

I have a Django project. It has a `settings.LANGUAGES` that looks a bit like the following:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', 'German'),
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('en-us', 'US English'),
)
```

I have a series of language codes, such that for each of them, `django.utils.translation.check_for_language()` returns `True`, i.e. they are supported by the project:

```
language_codes = ('en', 'en-us', 'en-gb', 'de', 'de-at')
```

I would like to transform `language_codes` such that each item is a language in `LANGUAGES`, i.e.:

```
transformed_language_codes = ('en', 'en-us', 'en', 'de', 'de')
```

I imagine Django does a similar transformation when looking for translations. However looking through `django.utils.translation.trans_real` hasn't uncovered anything that looks right. My best bet seems to be either hacking something up around `get_language_from_request()` to use the same substring logic, or writing something myself and debugging edge-cases around splitting.

Have I missed some useful function that exists to do this, or do I need to be writing it myself?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
class UnknownLanguageError(Exception):
    pass

def translate_languages(lang_codes, supported_languages):
    translated_languages = []
    for code in lang_codes: 
        if not code in supported_languages: 
            code = code[:2]
            if not code in supported_languages:
                raise UnknownLanguageError()
        translated_languages.append(code)

    return zip(lang_codes, translated_languages)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('de', 'German'),
        ('en', 'English'),
        ('en-us', 'US English'),
    )
    lang_codes = ('en', 'en-us', 'en-gb', 'de', 'de-at')
    lang_table = translate_languages(lang_codes, dict(LANGUAGES).keys())
    for t in lang_table:
        print '%s \t -> %s' % (t[0], t[1])
```